# Why does my Cloudformation Data Pipeline fail on my Ec2Resource?

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline, aws-cloudformation, data-pipeline

I’m trying to run a Data Pipeline inside a cloud formation stack. This stack references the exports of another stack which contains a Redshift cluster. When I run it, I get an error stating " 'Ec2Instance', errors = Internal error during validation of this object.”; but I am unable to find any more information on this error or what it means. Other objects show the same error, but they are dependent on Ec2Instance. Based on that, I’m assuming it’s a cascade situation.
Here’s my PipelineObject for the Ec2Instance.

```
{
"Id": "Ec2Instance",
"Name": "Ec2Instance",
"Fields": [
  {
    "Key": "type",
    "StringValue": "Ec2Resource"
  },
  {
    "Key": "role",
    "StringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultRole"
  },
  {
    "Key": "resourceRole",
    "StringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
  },
  {
    "Key": "terminateAfter",
    "StringValue": "1 Hour"
  },
  {
    "Key": "actionOnTaskFailure",
    "StringValue": "terminate"
  },
  {
    "Key": "actionOnResourceFailure",
    "StringValue": "retryAll"
  },
  {
    "Key": "maximumRetries",
    "StringValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "instanceType",
    "StringValue": "m1.medium"
  },
  {
    "Key": "securityGroupIds",
    "StringValue": "#{myRDSRedshiftSecurityGrps}"
  },
  {
    "Key": "subnetId",
    "StringValue": "#{myRedshiftClusterSubnetGroup}"
  }
]
}
```